# SoapCore errors

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, soapcore

I keep getting this issue when I attempt to visit the wsdl page for a service I created in .Net Core 3.0
The request reached the end of the pipeline without executing the endpoint: 'SoapCore'. Please register the EndpointMiddleware using 'IApplicationBuilder.UseEndpoints(...)' if using routing.

SoapCore version: 1.1.0.1-beta
I have also tried version 1.0.0 with the same result

Code:
Configure Services Function

```
    services.AddControllers();
    services.AddSoapCore();
    services.TryAddSingleton<MyService>();
    services.AddMvc();
```

Configure Function

```
    if (env.IsDevelopment() || env.IsEnvironment("local"))
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    }
    else
    {
        app.UseHsts();
    }

    app.UseHttpsRedirection();
   
    app.UseRouting();
    app.UseAuthorization();            

    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
    {
        endpoints.UseSoapEndpoint<MyService>("/Service.svc", new BasicHttpBinding(), SoapSerializer.DataContractSerializer);
        endpoints.MapControllers();
    });
```

Comment: See following : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/?view=aspnetcore-3.1

Answer (score 8):

It appears the the path is case sensitive. Sorry all, and if anyone is as aloof as me, make sure when visiting your route that you case it just as you have it in code.

Comment: There is a `UseSoapEndpoint()` overload that allows `caseInsensitivePath` to be set to `true` to resolve this. e.g. `endpoints.UseSoapEndpoint<MyService>("/Service.svc", new BasicHttpBinding(), SoapSerializer.DataContractSerializer, true);`